# Conditional Excel Dropdown Selection

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

I have aN Excel doc which contains several dropdowns in a row. Like this..
|DROPDOWN1||DROPDOWN2||DROPDOWN3||DROPDOWN4||DROPDOWN5|

The ordering is important as the dropdown values relate to specific parameters in a JavaScript query string.

DROPDOWN3 has about 15 possible values, but one of these values dictates the value that must appear in DROPDOWN1.
EG - If the value of DROPDOWN3 is 10, the value of DROPDOWN1 must be 5

My question is thus...

Is it possible that when the crucial value of DROPDOWN5 is selected I can force the selection of the dependent value in DROPDOWN1, as in conditional formulae?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: drop downs for data validation?

Comment: @alex.pulver Indeed, I guess what I'm trying to do is dependent data validation?

Comment: http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dependent-drop-down-lists.html